# Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...): arguments must have same length, with att_gt function

Tags: r

I am new to econometrics and I am trying to perform a Group-Time Average Treatment Effects by using the function att_gt() from the did() library in R studio. I am trying to estimate the effect of mergers on R&D expenditures. I have a treatment group with mergers happening in 2014, 2015 and 2016 and a control group with no mergers happening. For both treatment and control I have data either for 2010-2018 or 2011-2019.

I get the following error : Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) :
arguments must have same length

I created a subset with only the variables I am using in the code and made sure that they are all the same length. I also replaced all NAs with 0.
However, I still get the same error. Does anybody have an idea what could be going wrong here?

This is my data https://github.com/Hristi99/Mergering/blob/main/Mergers_data.xlsx

This is the code that I am using:

```
out <- att_gt(yname = "RD_Expense",
              gname = "treatment_year",
              idname = "Globa_Company_Key",
              tname = "Date_Year",
              xformla = ~SIC4 + ISO_Country_Code,
              allow_unbalanced_panel = TRUE,
              data = Mergers_dataset,
              )
summary(out)
```

I am trying to run this code because I have 3 treatment periods and I cannot think of aanother way to perform difference-in-differences. If anyone has other suggestions that would be appreciated.

Comment: I get an error trying to run your code. you can use `dput` to provide a sample of your data without us having to download external excel files.. `Error in DRDID::drdid_rc(y = Y, post = post, D = G, covariates = covariates,  : 
  Outcome regression model coefficients have NA components. 
 Multicollinearity (or lack of variation) of covariates is a likely reason.
In addition: Warning message:
In pre_process_did(yname = yname, tname = tname, idname = idname,  :
  dropped 3 rows from original data due to missing data`